# GeoDjango: Sort by country of the geolocation

Tags: python, django, join, geodjango

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I have a model which contains projects with the corresponding geolocation:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Project Name'), max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    geolocation = models.PointField(_('Project Location'))
    ...
```

In addition, another model is representing a shapefile with the country borders:

```
class WorldBorder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**How can I do a query on Project and order the results by the country name of the geolocation?**
A query like

> d = Project.objects.all().order_by(geolocation__name)

does not work since geolocation is not a Foreignkey. **Do I really have loop through all projects and determine the country manually like in my example below?**

```
projects = Project.objects.all()
result = []
for project in projects
    country = WorldBorder.objects.filter(mpoly__contains = project.geolocation)
    foo = [project.name, country]
    result.append(foo)
# now sort the list according to the country
result = sorted(result, key=itemgetter(1))
```

**There should be a more professional and elegant solution? Any suggestions from the experienced Python people?** Can I use joins for that purpose?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I think it might be better to add a country (ISO code) field to your Project model and update this accordingly when the PointField changes, I doubt projects would change location often, so this would save a lot of needless queries?